# compare number: 202.10.200 and 202.201.30

Tags: java, compare

How do I compare 2 numbers which can have the values 202.10.200 and 202.101.30 in java. I understand the above 2 cannot be "numbers". We need to compare this keeping in mind 202.101.30  should be greater than 202.10.200.

Comment: String split and parsing to integer is your key..

Comment: If they aren't numbers, then don't call them numbers. It might also help if you stated exactly what ordering you want. (For the record, it looks like you're comparing IP addresses or something)

Comment: Are the parts compared using the parts left to right as if they were integers?

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String inputLine = keyboard.nextLine();
String[] inputArray = inputLine.split(".");
int[] numArray = null;
for(int i = 0; i < inputArray<length; i++)
{ numArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputArray[i]);
}
```

Then you just need to write another loop to compare another two input arrays with different numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that strings are syntattically identical and have the same number of elements separated by ".", you can split them into arrays, convert arrays elements into int and then compare them onw by one:

```
String s1 = "202.10.200";
String s2 = "202.101.30";
String sGreater = s1;

String[] strArr1 = s1.split("\\.");
String[] strArr2 = s2.split("\\.");

for (int i=0; i<strArr1.length; i++)
{
  int x1 = Integer.parseInt(strArr1[i]);
  int x2 = Integer.parseInt(strArr2[i]);

  if (x2>x1)
  {
    sGreater = s2;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method can be used as an implementation of a Comparator:

```
public static int compareTo(String s1, String s2) {
    String[] a1 = s1.split("\\.");
    String[] a2 = s2.split("\\.");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (!a1[i].equals(a2[i]))
            return Integer.parseInt(a1[i]) - Integer.parseInt(a2[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works with any (but equal) number of integer groups separated by dots.

```
private static int compareDotNums(String str1, String str2) {
    if (str1 != null && str2 != null) {
        String[] split1 = str1.split("\\.");
        String[] split2 = str2.split("\\.");

        if (split1.length != split2.length)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input length mismatch.");

        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < split1.length; i++) {
            try {
                result = Integer.valueOf(split1[i]).
                                         compareTo(Integer.valueOf(split2[i]));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                                "Illegal input. Not a number.");
            }
            if (result != 0)
                break;
        }
        return result;
    } else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Non-null input required.");
}
```

***Sample Output:***

```
System.out.println(compareDotNums("202.10.200", "202.201.30"));  // -1
System.out.println(compareDotNums("202.210.200", "202.201.30")); // 0
System.out.println(compareDotNums("202.201.30", "202.201.30"));  // 1

System.out.println(compareDotNums("202.201.30.110", "202.201.30.128")); // -1
System.out.println(compareDotNums("202.201.30.128", "202.201.30.128")); // 0
System.out.println(compareDotNums("202.201.30.210", "202.201.30.128")); // 1
```